# updating data from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexeddb

I have a simple jquery mobile page, that should find id in indexedDb, and after you find it, update the rest of information, if that id record exist. (I have 10 records that I inserted  )
I can't find the right way to do it. I ether insert empty data, or my second button doesn't response, if I use code below
Here is my code:
js:

```
     let updateCompId = $("#updateCompId").val();
      $("#updateButton").click(function() {
              // var updateCompId = $("#updateCompId").val();
              let tx = db.transaction(["Clients"], 'readwrite');
              let store = tx.objectStore("Clients");

                      var readCompanyId = store.get(updateCompId);

                      if (readCompanyId = updateCompId) {

                            store.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
                            let cursor = event.target.result;
                            if (cursor) {
                                document.getElementById('updateForm').style.display = "";

                                cursor.continue();
                            }
                        };
                      }
});


  $("#updateInfo").click(function() {
    console.log("here");
        var tran = db.transaction(["Clients"], "readwrite");
        var store = tran.objectStore("Clients");
        // var compId = $("#updateCompId").val();

        var updateCompName = $("#updateCompName").val();
        var updatePost = $("#updatePost").val();
        var updateCompAddress = $("#updateCompAddress").val();
        var updateCity = $("#updateCity").val();
        var updateCountry = $("#updateCountry").val();
        var updateContact = $("#updateContact").val();
        var updatePhone = $("#updatePhone").val();
        var updateEmail = $("#updateEmail").val();

        var item = {
            id:updateCompId,
            Name:updateCompName,
            Post:updatePost,
            Address:updateCompAddress,
            City:updateCity,
            Country:updateCountry,
            Contact:updateContact,
            Phone:updatePhone,
            Email:updateEmail
        };
        console.log(item);
        store.put(item);
  });
```

HTML:

```
        <form id="findId">
          Enter Company Id to update information:
          <input id="updateCompId" type="text" name="updateCompId"/>
          <button id="updateButton" class="ui-btn">find to update</button>
          <p id="updateCustomer"></p>
          <button id="updateInfo" class="ui-btn">Update</button>
        </form>

        <form id="updateForm">
          Company name:
          <input id="updateCompName" type="text" name="compName"/>
          Post code:
          <input id="updatePost" type="text" name="post"/>
          Company address:
          <input id="updateCompAddress" type="text" name="compAddress"/>
          City:
          <input id="updateCity" type="text" name="city"/>
          Country:
          <input id="updateCountry" type="text" name="country"/>
          Contact number:
          <input id="updateContact" type="text" name="contact"/>
          Company phone:
          <input id="updatePhone" type="text" name="phone"/>
          Email:
          <input id="updateEmail" type="text" name="email"/>

        </form>
```

Comment: Do you repeat those forms for every record?

Comment: Do you understand what the line `if (readCompanyId = updateCompId)` is doing?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take some time to read more about IndexedDB. [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb) docs for it and the [W3 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB-2/) are good for this.

For your question, you have a `get` whose result you are trying to compare to some other value. This is wrong because all interactions with IndexedDB are asynchronous and return an `IDBRequest` instance with `onsuccess` and `onerror` callbacks. You can get your `get` result in the `onsuccess` callback, but what you are doing instead is comparing an actual value to an `IDBRequest` instance.